# Significant factor in 2-way repeated ANOVA becomes not significant in 3-way repeated ANOVA?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, normality-assumption

My research design is 2(Ear) x 3(Factor A) x 3(Factor B) with repeated measures on all factors. For 2 way-repeated ANOVA, I used laterality index (normal distribution, calculated from % of responses from both ears) as dependent variable (DV) while Factor A and B are independent variables (IV). I obtained significant main and interaction effects.

However, when I tried 3-way repeated ANOVA using % scores from each ear as DV, factor B becomes not significant. I'm not sure what could be wrong?

1. Is it because the % scores in one of the conditions were not normally distributed with p=0.041? The box plot looks alright but histogram has an inverted bell curve shape. I've tried log, square root and 1/x transformation but didn't work. Is it acceptable to run ANOVA since there's no equivalent non-parametric test in SPSS?
2. Could it be the way I run the test in SPSS? I followed exactly the same way as I did for 2-way repeated ANOVA because I couldn't find any examples similar to my research design. Most examples have a third between subject factor while mine are all within subject factors.

I'd really appreciate any help or suggestions because I'm confused and new with statistics.
Many thanks.

Kaye

Comment: Nothing need be wrong. There is no reason this can't happen. A 3 way ANOVA asks a different question than a 2 way ANOVA, and when you ask a different question, you shouldn't be surprised at a different answer.

In particular, adding a factor controls for that factor.

Comment: You might use the search feature to look around a bit. Questions about the significance of different factors & changes in the significance as factors are added, etc, have been pretty common.

Comment: @PeterFlom I'm just puzzled because the DVs in both analysis are related, as in the laterality index came from the % scores. If adding a factor changes everything, then my concern is if it's valid to run the 3-way ANOVA in the first place considering the lack of normality? perhaps I could justify by saying the p is near to 0.05?

Comment: @gung. Thanks for your suggestion. I've done a bit of poking around but haven't found what I need.

Comment: Don't think in terms of p values, think in terms of effect size. Did it change much? 

But, again, you are asking a different question.

Comment: Peter Flom hit the nail on the head.  The three-way ANOVA estimates more parameters, which requires more statistical power.  If your study is already underpowered (because you have few participants, for example), this can easily increase p-values above .05, even if your observed effect sizes remain the same.  I'd recommend finding what your observed power is for the 2- and 3-way ANOVAs, either using the option in SPSS or by using a specialty calculator like [G*Power](http://www.psycho.uni-duesseldorf.de/aap/projects/gpower/). -Patrick

Comment: @PeterFlom You got me thinking about the question part. Just to clarify the one that I mentioned is from Shapiro Wilk normality test. Anyway for Factor B, the effect size did change from large to medium.

Comment: @Patrick Yes. The observed power reduced as well, from 1 to 0.34. The thing with analysis is, I key in numbers and get more numbers. Beats me whether I'm doing it right.

Comment: Getting you thinking is good! So, that means that controlling for the third factor reduced the effect of Factor B. I don't know what these factors are (can you tell us?) so I can't say what that means, substantively.

Comment: @PeterFlom Factor A is attention and Factor B is the intensity difference between both ears.

Comment: So, when you added the third factor (ear), the relationship between intensity difference and laterality index weakened.

Comment: @PeterFlom Is that so? I used different DV though. When I added the third factor, I used scores from the right and left ear respectively instead of laterality index. They are similar but not same? Got me thinking again.

Comment: If you used a different DV then all bets are off. There is no reason to expect similar answers at all.